# what element i need to use to build game like this

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

i am building a game which is similar to the [Plain Jane Flash Game](http://www.mefeedia.com/game/31189952) for the iPad. I have decided to use cocos2d for the same, while exploring the cocos2d there are lots of option i am having. i am confuse in which elements/controls would be best for this type of game Please guide me or share any link/tutorial on cocos2d which have similar user interface.

I mean shall i use CCMenu/CCmenuItem or there is another control which is more suitable... 
shall i use Sprite or simple image would be sufficent as i do not need to move anything in it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your question was not very clear, I assume your referring to the functionality of dragging and dropping different clothing items onto the game avatars. A custom CCSprite object would be much more appropriate for doing that.

However, there is not an easy answer for what you are asking. Creating a game like "Plane Jane" will involve many problems that I'm sure have not crossed your mind. I recommend you complete a few Cocos2d-iPhone tutorials before you go any further. Once you do that, you will have a much better understanding of the functionality you will need to create your game.

Here is a nice tutorial for starters:
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/582